# Showing a specific view controller on load

Tags: ios, swift

In some cases I want my app to present a different view controller than the one that normally loads (in this case *AltView* rather than *MainView*), but I can't figure out how to do it. I tried like this:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Alt", bundle: nil)
let nav = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AltView")   

 let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
 let rootVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainView")
 self.window!.rootViewController = rootVC
 window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

 self.window!.rootViewController?.presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But nothing happens, the screen is just blank, no errors or warnings are being reported.

EDIT: *AltView* is an `UINavigationController` with an embedded `UIViewController`. The `viewDidLoad()` method of *AltView*'s embedded view controller is being run, but its `viewWillAppear()` method is not.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This code is written is in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions right??

Answer (score 0):

Just set the window controller like this

```
    let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let nav = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AltView") 
    self.window!.rootViewController = nav
```

If u want to change the controller change the window rootviewcontroller again with same code just change the identifier to the one that you want of the controller and you don't need this statement  `self.window!.rootViewController?.presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
If you face any issues let me know

Comment: This doesn't work for me because _MainView_ needs to be the root controller, or the unwind segue and some other stuff won't work. And if I change the root view controller back to _MainView_ when the _AltView_ appears, the view changes to _MainView_ which is not what I want.

Comment: How about if you pop the same navigation controller to mainView and push altview in there